# How can I have searchkick autocomplete on multiple fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j, searchkick, neo4j.rb

Is it possible to use multiple fields for searchkick's autocomplete feature? It seems to be searching only the first field specified.

For example, for a person with the `first_name` "Foo" and `last_name` "Bar"

`Person.search("Fo", fields: [first_name: :text_start, last_name: :text_start])`
- *returns result*

`Person.search("Ba", fields: [first_name: :text_start, last_name: :text_start])` - *no results found*

Comment: it think text_start missing ":" for last name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with it, but I think so.  From the docs:

https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#autocomplete

```
City.search "san fr", fields: [{name: :text_start}]
```

That seems to imply that you can give an Array of Hashes.  When you don't specify the squiggly brackets like you do that will make one Array with one Hash.

Comment: good catch but I'm having the same issue with `Person.search("Ba", fields: [{first_name: :text_start}, {last_name: :text_start}])`

Comment: Hrmm, I'm not sure.  The docs seem to indicate that something like that would work.  Do you have the `word_start` specified in the `searchkick` call?  This is what it shows for one field: `searchkick word_start: [:name]`

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I had removed `last_name` from the `searchkick` call during debugging and it was ultimately the missing `{}` that caused the issue.

Comment: Yay, nice.  Good luck! ;)